# How to properly handle intercepting a Fragment's/ Activity up navigation top back arrow( <- ) so fragment/Activity only closes based on a condition

Tags: android, dialog, navigation, alert

Pls I want to show an alert dialog after the up navigation arrow(up button) is clicked. But I don't want it to go back if certain conditions are not met.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            if(!(editGroceryName.equals(oldGroceryName))){
                showWarningAlert();
                return false;
            } else{return true;}
            
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I added the alert dialog code within android.R.id.home on the onOptionsItemSelected() method but the dialog shows briefly then closes with the hosting activity then navigates back to MainActivity which was initially on back stack. Pls here is my code from SecondActivity

Pls what can I add to the code so it doesn't go back or so that only the alert dialog positive OK button can close the activity

Comment: What do you mean by up button? is that the triangle in the navigation bar that takes you back? If so you can override onBackPressed() and leave it empty, so as not to take you back to the last activity and leave the alert dialog showing

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, This fixed it for me. Returning true means you're handling things, so fragment doesn't close. While false tells the system you have no objection and that it should proceed in closing the fragment/Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            if(!(editGroceryName.equals(oldGroceryName))){ // Name is different
                showExitWarningAlert();
                return true; // Handled - Fragment do not close
            } else{return false;}
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```